# What is an alternative to Jetty? I'm looking for a simple javax.servlet container

Tags: java, servlets

What is an alternative to [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Wiki)? I'm looking for a simple javax.servlet container. Jetty is too complex for the task I'm working with. And its documentation is very poor.

PS. I created my own web framework: [takes.org](http://www.takes.org)

Comment: Yes, sure, it's even bigger. I need something small and embeddable. I'm going to create my own RESTful standalone (!) application

Comment: Right to the point, that's what I was looking for, thanks! :) (please convert your comment to an answer an I'll accept it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Possible Alternatives

- [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin/)
- [Tiny Java Web Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tjws/)
- [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) (a bit outdated)
- or if you want JAX-RS support, then [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is the reference implementation

#### Simple, But Not Too Simple

That being said, except if you are really constrained, why wouldn't a minimalist config of [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or even [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) work for you?

If complexity is an issue, then maybe you should **start with Tomcat first** and then see how Jetty (or others) could be used and how it would fit your goals **later**. Tomcat is not that heavyweight, and at least you'll have **plenty** of documentation and examples to look at.

---

**Update:** As you mention in the comment that you need JAX-RS support, Jersey is indeed a good option. Have a look at [Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/)'s article on [REST with Java using Jersey](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) for a good ramp-up.

Comment: Jersey is the REST engine that runs on/in a server like Jetty. Grizzly would be the alternative to Jetty.

Answer (score 11):

Try Grizzly, which is the standalone part of Jersey (JAX-RS implementation).

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about embedding jetty? This is instead of deploying your app in jetty, embedding jetty in your app.

I used before and it's quite easy. Here's some documentation:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Answer (score 1):

JBoss (which is now called Wildfly) and Tomcat are good alternatives to Jetty. This article talks about some of the differences between the two. http://www.futurehosting.com/jboss-vs-tomcat-choosing-a-java-application-server/